# Fitnesse read only mode?

Tags: fitnesse

Is it possible to set fitnesse into a read-only mode?

For the software delivery lifecycle it makes sense to have 'edit' and 'test' modes but I was wondering if fitnesse can be made read only so that we can use it as our documentation site for anyone that wants to view and not edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. That is what http://fitnesse.org is: a readonly FitNesse server.
One needs to override some 'Responders' in the `plugins.properties` file, so that all responders that cause updates or run tests are disabled as described in the [documentation](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.ConfigurationFile) under 'Disabled Responders'. A list of all available Responders can be found [here](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices).

See https://github.com/fitnesse/fitnessedotorg/blob/master/plugins.properties for how fitnesse.org does it

```
Responders =addChild:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,createDir:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,delete:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,deleteConfirmation:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,deleteFile:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,deletePage:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,edit:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,executeSearchProperties:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,executeSearchProperties:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,files:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,fitClient:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,import:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,movePage:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,names:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,new:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,packet:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,pageData:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,properties:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,proxy:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,refactor:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,releaseDownload:com.objectmentor.fitnesse.releases.DownloadResponder,renameConfirmation:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,renameFile:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,renamePage:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,replace:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,rollback:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,saveData:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,saveProperties:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,search:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,shutdown:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,socketCatcher:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,suite:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,symlink:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,test:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,upload:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,whereUsed:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,partition:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder
```

But my recommendation would be to publish the html results of tests as documentation (for a given release). These can provide some additional insight by showing actual results and not just expectations.

Comment: Disabling the responders would work but the buttons would still show up on the pages as discussed in https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/1157

Comment: Are you sure the buttons are still shown? On for instance http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteWidgetTests I do not see any buttons and the site really is served by FitNesse

Comment: I tested this on my system and yes, the buttons still showed up. But I was not using the current FitNesse version.